# using glide in switch (in DataFakeGenerator class)

Tags: java, android

I would use glide for load image in android studio but I'm having trouble.
I try to use common methods but I didn't.
please help me to use glide in switch.

this codes are without using glide;
I'm going to use glide instead

```
enter code herepublic class DataFaceGenerator {                                        //(5)
            public static List<Cloth>getClothes(Context context){
                List<Cloth>cloths=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i <=8 ; i++) {
                    Cloth cloth=new Cloth();
                    cloth.setId(i);
                    cloth.setTitle("لورم ایپسوم");
                    cloth.setViewCountString("700");

                    switch (i){
                        case 1:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe1,null));break;
                        case 2:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe2,null));break;
                        case 3:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe4,null));break;
                        case 4:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe5,null));break;
                        case 5:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe5,null));break;
                        case 6:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe6,null));break;
                        case 7:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe7,null));break;
                        case 8:cloth.setImage(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.qwe8,null));break;

                    }
                    cloths.add(cloth);
                    }
                return cloths;
                {
}
```

Comment: Please upload the code along with the post.

Comment: I don't have any code.I ask you what code to write.
Please suggest.

Comment: This is just object where your putting your drawables in. Where do you will use this getClothes method in recyclerview ? there you will write the logic of loading image using Glide.